# Tricky Mac Virus

Tags: usb, virus

I have no idea how this happened but I have some insanely hard to find worm on my mac. I was trying to wipe an old external HHD I had to back up a Time Machine and it must have had some malware, did not realize Mac's could get a virus like this from USB plug-ins (or at least very rare)

The software is called Easy Suite and appears as a CD even though it was a hard drive passing the virus along. I did not realize it was a virus until directly connecting two of my Macbook pros and saw the that instead of displaying my hard drive on the computer, this CD drive is displayed as the only usable disk from the other device.

It becomes even weirder when you inspect the drive it has a .inf and .exe (both windows specific?) I have no idea how it is spreading or where it could be hiding. I have checked ~/Library/Cache as well as /library/cache. Additionally, ran malwarebytes and still seeing the same issues when connecting two devices. My user account has read & write privileges but cannot delete any of the files. Starting to concerned, any idea what directory these files are hiding in, any advice is greatly appreciated [image]

Comment: I also completely wiped the computer and reinstalled OS.

Answer (score 4):

That looks more like someone else on your local subnet is sharing their CD player, which will be why you can't find it locally.

Remote CDs are listed under Locations. If nothing else shows in that section, make sure they're switched on in Finder Prefs > Sidebar

Your choices are:-

- Find whoever's sharing & ask them to switch it off
  System Prefs > Sharing
  or on Windows, Control Panel > Hardware and Sound

or…

- Ignore it
  Finder > Prefs > Sidebar

See Apple KB - [Use the CD or DVD drive from another computer with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT203973)

Comment: This still doesn't explain why connecting two Macbooks together, they show up as CD drives.... literally cannot view the contents of my hard drive when directly connecting, just displays EasySuite CD drive

Comment: If you have further information please add it to your original question. Your comment doesn't tell me anything about whether you've even tested any of my suggestions.

Comment: My apologies, I can switch my finder preferences to display my hard disks but still super weird why this EasySuite CD drive shows up when my macbook is plugged in to each other. And in disk utility I still cant see my hard drive. When I plug my macbook into my other macbook it just displays a CD drive in disk utility